# Unexplained Problem with my Review Queues

Tags: discussion, bug, review

In my review queue, it shows this.

[image]

This is a bit weird. My reputation, as seen on the picture, is 839, clearly enough to access First Posts and Late Answers. However, it is not shown on the top anymore. I am not sure why I am having this problem. I was still able to access them earlier today, and so it's just extremely weird. It's the first time I have encountered this though. Is this a bug in Math SE, or is this a status by design?

Comment: Please stop changing the question you ask at the end of the post.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I had realized that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/503528/kinglogic?tab=topactivity) shows you've voted 40 times today, which means you have no votes left. Since voting (up or down) is one of the most important things to do in the First Posts and Late Answers queues, you cannot review if you're out of votes.

[image]