# Allow users to still access First Post and Late Answer even though the user has no votes left

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I know that from the answer to [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32654/unexplained-problem-with-my-review-queues) that "if you are not able to use the full range of options in the queue, it is better to give the reviewer's role to someone who is."

However, I disagree with this take on the issue. Even though a user cannot vote after the daily maximum is reached, he or she can still comment on and flag questions/answers. If there are users who are enthusiastic to contribute to the community, we shouldn't stop them from doing so. Do you agree with my stance on this?

Comment: You don't need to rely on the review queues to flag or comment on posts.  You can still contribute in these ways by reading posts, and flagging those with problems, or flagging comments with problems, and you can comment, without doing so through review queues.

Comment: Also, everyone of us deals with quotas in votes, edits permitted, flags, etc., and over time, many of us learn the need to pace ourselves, and not necessarily use our entire quotas in a short period of time. Else, one feels frustrated for the rest of the day.  I've learned to try and use my votes and actions wisely, and not too quickly, to avoid that frustration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I disagree with the premise of this question. Sometimes when reviewing a first post or a late answer, the proper response is to vote up or down, which can't be done if you've maxed out votes. If you would risk doing the job improperly, wait a few hours and do it right, especially since the stakes are so low and for those two queues there are usually many available reviewers.

Answer (score 7):

While there is no *technical* limitation to reviewing when you cannot take the entire range of possible actions, I think that it is not within the spirit of the review queues to review when you can't take action.

1. Often, the right action is to up/downvote a question, or vote to close.  If you cannot takes one of those actions, but those actions are possible for clearing a review item, then you will sometimes (often?) be unable to take the correct action with respect to review items.  Your options are either to perform the wrong action, or to skip the review item.  If you consistently do either of these things, you might end up banned from reviewing.
2. The system imposes limits on users (in part) to prevent any one user from having too much influence over the site.  Hitting your daily limit is the site's way of saying "Okay, let someone else have a turn now."  Continuing to take action in the review queues could be seen as a way of circumventing this kind of rate limiting.
3. You currently don't have enough reputation to participate in all of the review queues.  Once you get [enough reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to interact with the "Close Votes" review queue, you might notice that it is perpetually over 300 items long.  By contrast, the queues in which you can participate with only up/downvotes are typically pretty short, and get handled quickly by the community.  These queues don't *need* your input, and so if you can't completely participate, it is best to let someone else take a turn.

In short, while a desire to participate and help maintain the site is admirable, if you can't fully participate (e.g. if you have used all of your up/downvotes, or close votes, or daily edits), then please do not take on review tasks.  Wait a few hours until you are again able to take *any* appropriate action.